# Debug jupyter notebook that uses multiprocessing in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use multiprocessing in a juypter notebook to cut down the processing time. Unfortunately it seems it's not possible to use the debugger in Visual Studio Code to debug anything after the Pool has been created. At first I get this error message:

> Couldn't find a debug adapter descriptor for debug type 'Python Kernel Debug Adapter'
> (extension might have failed to activate)

Followed by this error message for every child process that was created:

> Failed to launch debugger for child process X

This is the code in the jupyter cell

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from func import x

with Pool(4) as p:
    results = p.map(x, [1,2,3,4])

for i in results:  # breakpoint
    print(i)
```

It also requires a file 'func.py':

```py
def x(y):
    return y
```

I also tried adding this as suggested in the vscode documentation, but with no effect:

```py
import debugpy
debugpy.debug_this_thread()
```

Is there any way to debug a jupyter notebook that uses multiprocessing with vscode?
OS: Windows 10
Python: 3.11
VSCode: 1.74.1

Comment: I've been having the same error msgs and the problem seems to trace back to multiprocessing (thanks for pointing me in that direction).  I opened a bug report here:  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/20432 .  I have seen a solution of putting  "subProcess": true into launch.json in vscode.  Unfortunately, this had no effect for me (am using Community Edition, which might react differently).

Comment: I've been looking for an alternative to VS Code that allows me to debug code with multiprocessing steps.  I found that the Pydev extension in Eclipse works, but notebook must be exported to .py file.  You can also debug inside VS Code using ipdb or pdb-- command line debuggers that need to be triggered by breakpoints added to the code.  Had a hard time stepping to the next line in a cell with these, because they want to go through all the code called by the current line, but setting a breakpoint to the next line from command line and continuing to it works.